# Compiling in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I'm compiling a project that was copied from another application file by file from XCODE IDE.
After compilation I get the following error:

```
Error: could not read data from '/Users/heziflashner/Documents/#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "MapKit/MapKit.h"
 #import "CoreLocation/UserLocationAddress/salesShare03/salesShare03/salesShare03-Info.plist':
```

The file “salesShare03-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

I'm trying to change the framework directory but with no success.
Any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

For framework headers you must use:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have a file making a reference to `saleseShare03-Info.plist`. Be sure you have that in your project tree, even try to remove it and then add it again. Else check your .xcodeproj file and check the settings. Copying a project this way is always tricky, good luck.